# wifi keeps droping every minute on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am running ubuntu 12.04 on my samsung laptop but the wifi connection keeps dropping every  minute. I have another dell laptop which also has ubuntu 12.04 but wifi works fine on that. And if I use my samsung laptop at office as its my office laptop wifi works fine. So, I don't understand what the problem is. I have googled it and found solution like set ignoring  IPv6 setting but that still does not make any difference.

So I don't understand where the problem is if its with my network provider or its with my laptop. I can't blame my network provider as wifi works fine on my other devices including Ipad, mobiles and dell laptop. Even I can't say clearly that its problem with my laptop as wifi works fine in my office.

Previously I had ubuntu 13.04 on my samsung laptop and I was having the same issue so I uninstall it and install 12.04 and issues is still the same.

I ran following commends with output

```
   lsmod | grep rtl
```

shows nothing

```
   iwconfig | grep Power
   lo        no wireless extensions.

   eth0      no wireless extensions.

      Power Management:off



     cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e etwork -e wlan | tail -n20
 Oct 29 21:49:05 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Activation  (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
 Oct 29 21:49:05 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
 Oct 29 21:49:05 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
 Oct 29 21:49:05 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
 Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
 Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
 Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
 Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Marking connection 'Wired connection 1' invalid.
Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <warn> Activation (eth0) failed.
Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Policy set 'VM733532-2G' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Oct 29 21:49:25 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Policy set 'VM733532-2G' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Oct 29 21:53:41 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 30)
Oct 29 21:53:41 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [30 20 40]
Oct 29 21:53:41 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
Oct 29 21:53:41 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Policy set 'VM733532-2G' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Oct 29 21:53:41 hgill-RF511-RF411-RF711 NetworkManager[833]: <info> Policy set 'VM733532-2G' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
```

I ran

```
 lsmod

 Module                  Size  Used by
 usb_storage            39646  0 
 nls_utf8               12493  1 
 udf                    84576  1 
 crc_itu_t              12627  1 udf
 michael_mic            12540  8 
 arc4                   12473  4 
 snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
 snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1 
 parport_pc             32114  0 
 ppdev                  12849  0 
 rfcomm                 38139  12 
 bnep                   17830  2 
 joydev                 17393  0 
 snd_hda_intel          32719  5 
 snd_hda_codec         109562  3        snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
 snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
 snd_pcm                80916  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
 snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
 snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
 snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
 snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
 snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
 snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
 snd                    62218  19      snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,sn     d_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
 lib80211_crypt_tkip    17275  0 
 uvcvideo               67203  0 
 btusb                  17948  2 
 mac_hid                13077  0 
 bluetooth             158447  23 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
 videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
 psmouse                86546  0 
 serio_raw              13027  0 
 wl                   2906597  0 
 soundcore              14635  1 snd
 i915                  428127  4 
 snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
 drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
 drm                   197641  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
 i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
 video                  19115  1 i915
 mei                    36570  0 
 cfg80211              178877  1 wl
 lib80211               14040  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
 lp                     17455  0 
 parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
 usbhid                 41937  0 
 hid                    77428  1 usbhid
 r8169                  56396  0
```

Comment: First, let's see what driver you have: lsmod | grep rtl And whether or not power management is off: iwconfig | grep Power And as soon as your wifi disconnects , run : ~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e etwork -e wlan | tail -n20 I really have no business leaving an answer on here, but I know if you run these commands and post the results in your OP (Edit your question with the results you get from these commands) Then you might have a better chance of getting a pro to help out. Also, do you have an etherent cable? Can you connect via etherent to see if it still disconnects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution as no one was able to help. The problem with my Broadcom STA wireless driver. I deactivate it and restart the machine and now problem gone. very happy now :)