# Wifi dongle hanging connection every couple of minutes 14.04

Tags: wireless

I'm running a fresh install off ubuntu 14.04 and using the following wifi adpter:

lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

My connection is really unstable a disconnects after a couple of minutes. Then I need to disable the wifi and re-activate it.

Here is some more info (based on this issues: [wifi keeps droping every minute on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368126/wifi-keeps-droping-every-minute-on-ubuntu-12-04))

lsmod | grep rtl

```
rtl8192cu              67723  0 
rtl_usb                18448  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53172  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              626489  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

iwconfig | grep Power

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

          Bit Rate=6.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Power Management:off



May  3 17:03:34 Guava dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.26 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x237c41a8)
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info>   address 192.168.1.26
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.254
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.254'
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.254'
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info>   domain name 'lan'
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
May  3 17:03:34 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
May  3 17:03:34 Guava avahi-daemon[829]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.26.
May  3 17:03:34 Guava avahi-daemon[829]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May  3 17:03:34 Guava avahi-daemon[829]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.26 on wlan0.IPv4.
May  3 17:03:35 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
May  3 17:03:35 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
May  3 17:03:35 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
May  3 17:03:35 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
May  3 17:03:35 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> Policy set 'HomeWIFI' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
May  3 17:03:35 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
May  3 17:03:35 Guava NetworkManager[939]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just followed this https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7 and it's working fine now.

Ubuntu should use this drivers by default.

Regards.